# How to determine if a state is entangled or pure in general?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, quantum-states

Given a state like $a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle+c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle$ where $a,b,c,d$ satisfy normalization, how can we know if it's pure?

Comment: You are confusing the pure/mixed distinction with the entangled/separable distinction. A state can be pure and entangled. The state you've given is pure and might be entangled depending on the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

It is a pure state because it is a single state, and not a collection of states with assigned classical probabilities.  A pure state can be entangled. Entanglement and purity are not the same thing.

Comment: Got it. And is there a general way to determine the pure state is entangled or not?

Comment: @yiping:  Try computing the value of $ad-bc$ for an unentangled state.

Comment: To decide whether the state is entangled it needs to refer to two separate systems. It's only when you write ${\mathcal H}_{tot}= {\mathcal H}_1\otimes {\mathcal H}_2$ that you can ask whether a  state $|\psi\rangle$ is entangled or not. It is *no*t entagled  if it can be written as  $|\psi\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle \otimes |\psi_2\rangle$.